# How to make vector from azimuth and speed?

Tags: vectors, physics

I don't know how to make $3$D vector of speed from azimuth and speed.

Azimuth is in *degree* and speed is in *m/s*.

Azimuth is angle on $X$ and $Y$.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In spherical polar coordinates:

$\mathbf{v}=
\dot{r} \mathbf{e}_{r}+
r\dot{\theta} \mathbf{e}_{\theta}+
r\dot{\phi} \sin \theta \mathbf{e}_{\phi}$

If the motion is confined in $xy$-plane, then $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\dot{\theta}=0$.

Thus, $\mathbf{v}=\dot{r} \mathbf{e}_{r}+r\dot{\phi} \mathbf{e}_{\phi}$